# Doing something on the value only if key exists in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, styles

I have the following snippets, among which I cannot find the clear winner.
Which style would you recommend? Is there anything better than these?

(assuming `self.task.flags` is a dictionary)

1. `in` and `[]`

   ```
   if 'target_names' in self.task.flags:
       foo(self.task.flags['target_names'])
   ```

   This mentions the names of the dictionary and the key twice (violating DRY).

   I can also imagine that this does the identical lookup twice internally,
   throwing away the value in the first case (`in`).
2. `get` and temporary variable

   ```
   value = self.task.flags.get('target_names')
   if value:
       foo(value)
   ```

   This removes the repetition, but a temporary variable is not very elegant.

   The meaning is also subtly different from the others, when
   `{'target_names': None}` is present in `self.task.flags`.
3. exceptions ("EAFP")

   ```
   try:
       foo(self.task.flags['target_names'])
   except KeyError:
       pass
   ```

   I hear that EAFP is generally encouraged in Python, but I still fear
   that exceptions can be expensive, especially when the chance of the key
   being present is not very high.

   This may also mask any exceptions raised inside `foo`.

   And the `try`…`except` structure can be visually distracting;
   even more when other exception handling is involved.

Comment: It solely depends on the context. One of the ways would be more elegant than the others in different situations.

Comment: The second assumption isn't a good one, since if the value is False or None, or '', 0, or any null value, it'll falsely not trigger the function call.

The second one only works if you know the possible scope of values.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh: Thanks; I have already stated the difference in its meaning, though it didn't include other false values (`False`, `0`, `''`).

Comment: Really though, it's as you wish. Context determines everything. I'd recommend against option 2, but... Context matters.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh: Thanks. I should have added that in the original context we can safely assume that the values in the dictionary are not false; `foo(value)` is actually something like `args.append('--target_names=%s' % value)`.

Answer (score 1):

ugly way:

```
# with impossibleValue being anything that can't possibly be one of your 
# values, like self.task.flags or an Object created here and now, like i'll do now.
impossibleValue = Object()

# dict.get(key, defaultValue) returns dict[key] if key 
# is in dict, otherwise returns defaultValue.
value = self.task.flags.get('target_names', impossibleValue)
if value != impossibleValue:
    foo(value)
```

Comment: If you're going to suggest this approach then at least do so by demonstrating how to create `IMPOSSIBLEVALUE`... the easiest way would be to use `sentinel = object()` to guarantee a unique object then use an identity check such as `if value is not sentinel`...

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: point taken, incoming edit

Answer (score 1):

Really, it's up to you. No substantial performance differences, the main worry is just be careful with the second form. If your values are null, and so they don't trigger the "if/then" clause, you will falsely assume there is no key.

```
a = {k:k**2 for k in range(1000000)}
def nullfunc(*args, **kwargs):
    del args, kwargs

def infunc(a):
    if 5000 in a:
        nullfunc(a[5000])

def getvalue(a):
    value = a.get(5000)
    if value:
        nullfunc(value)

def tryexcept(a):
    try:
        nullfunc(a[5000])
    except KeyError:
        pass


In [12]: %timeit infunc(a)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 238 ns per loop

In [13]: %timeit getvalue(a)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 256 ns per loop

In [14]: %timeit tryexcept(a)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 197 ns per loop

In [15]:
```

Comment: Thanks for the experiment. On the other hand, if the key is not present (e.g. you do `del a[5000]`), `tryexcept` performs the worst *by far*.

Comment: True, but Python has the EFAP principle for this reason:
"It's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission (EFAP)".

http://www.python-academy.com/courses/specialtopics/python_patterns.html

It's true: it

Comment: True, but Python has the EFAP principle for this reason:
"It's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission (EFAP)".

http://www.python-academy.com/courses/specialtopics/python_patterns.html

It's true: it's much slower if you have to except everything, but you are writing your code expecting it to work.

The times with trying -1 (which is not there) are:
infunc -- 82.3 ns, getvalue -- 136 ns, tryexcept, 630 ns.

Getting rid of option 2 for obvious reason... We get a similar performance when the key is in ~90% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Both the first and the third options make sense to me. I prefer to reserve try/except for cases that are actually exceptional, and not expected results (user error for example). If it makes sense for the flag to not be there a lot of the time, I would personally prefer case 1. It may also make sense to do the inverse of it if there is *no* code to be executed if the flag is not there, i.e.:

```
def foo(self, some_other_args):
    ... do something ...
    if 'target_names' not in self.task.flags:
        # Nothing further to do here, so return the result
        return result

    ... do something with self.task.flags['target_names'] ...
    return result
```

However I know some people like to avoid multiple returns like that. If you truly expect 'target_names' to be present in the dictionary, I think your case 3 is probably the better solution, because it makes the intent clear (that the missing key is truly exceptional, not the standard case).

Answer (score 1):

The third way, since as you said it conforms to EAFP.

Note that the try/except clause can be written more succintly in this case (Python 3.4+):

```
import contextlib
with contextlib.suppress(KeyError):
    foo(self.task.flags['target_names'])
```